# Creating a Hash from retrieved XML

Tags: xml, ruby-on-rails-3, hash, xml-parsing

I have read a few posts that advice you can create a Hash from XML using Rails built in method

```
from_xml
```

so for example i could do

```
Hash.from_xml(object)
```

In my case I am retrieving XML from an api and using Nokogiri to parse it, like so

```
url = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?client_id=#{client_id}&access_token=#{current_user.token}&max-results=#{max_results}";
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(url))
```

Now if i try

```
Hash.from_xml(doc)
```

I receive a REXML parse error. Is this because i need to create the Hash from unparsed XML?

I am looking to gain a better understanding of this, documents i have read seem to be very high level, if any could offer just a basic explanation or point to a resource that does, I can read it and look to gain a better understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is expecting a string.

Although [this docs page](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/from_xml/class) doesn't say so in its method description, it's clear from the example in the notes that the input should be an XML string.

You should be able to do:

```
Hash.from_xml(open(url).read)
```

**Edit:** It appears that, under Rails, Nokogiri has a `to_hash` method. So you can also do:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(url))
xml_hash = doc.to_hash
```

Comment: sorry to ask what i guess may be a silly question, but how do i ensure that the returned XML is a string?

Comment: and yes from now reading the docs I can see the the XML in the example is a string, thanks

Comment: @Richlewis - Edited answer in. Although, given the restriction shown on the docs page, might you be better using something else? A quick google suggests [Nori](https://github.com/savonrb/nori)

Comment: is it Nokogiri causing the issue here? i could use HTTParty as an alternative?

Comment: What I mean is; if you want a Hash from your XML, Nokogiri doesn't give you one. But `Hash.from_xml` is apparently bugged, according to the docs. You could try a different gem, such as Nori. That said, Nokogiri under Rails apparently has a `to_hash` method, although I can't say whether it's bugged too.